# Left Button doesnt Appear [XML Layout]

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I might be doing something wrong in this layout, I already spent an hour try to find the bug, and I cant find it..
The first button which text is "-", doesn't appear..

Here is the layout in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accuracyMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textAccuracy"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textAccuracy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Accuracy Buttons"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accuracyPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textAccuracy"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="+" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in LinearLayout

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: You welcome, you always take parent width and height = "fill_parent", so that it can fill your entire mob screen

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes to your layout to make the "-"button visible, below is the updated code. Also I tried it inside a linear layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAccuracy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Accuracy Buttons"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accuracyMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textAccuracy"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accuracyPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textAccuracy"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="+" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the solution, its a good answer, if someone want the xml layout correct solution, but I got already an answer accepted. Thanks mate ;)

Comment: Well I notice now that there is a bug, on both buttons change from @+id/textAccuracy to @id/textAccuracy   . Because since you put the TextView before and created using @+id/textAccuracy, on the below components u just need to put the tag to it, u dont need to create them ;)

Comment: I submite an edit to your post, fixing what I said at the comment before ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this code. In my device left button is appearing

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accuracyMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textAccuracy"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textAccuracy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Accuracy Buttons"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accuracyPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textAccuracy"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="+" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: On my device it didnt, maybe because the relative layout is inside another layout, I have it inside in a linear layout vertical, with other components. But thanks for your effort ! ;)